# Why is there an extra space between elements when writing HTML in new line

Tags: html, css

Here is a snippet for this issue.

```html
HTML for 2 Buttons written in one line:<br />
<button>Button 1</button><button>Button 2</button>

<br /><br />

HTML for 2 Buttons written in different lines:<br />
<button>Button 1</button>
<button>Button 2</button>
```

The thing is that I'm minimizing my code, comprising of HTML, CSS and JS. Upon minimizing, the space between elements decreases as can be seen in the snippet above. How can we avoid this?

Comment: what do you mean by the space is reduced  ?  your elements doesn't have padding or margin between them

Comment: New line is a "whitespace", and `<button>` is an inline element, so the new line in code does not create a new line in the output, but still counts as a space.

Comment: @FaizalHussain Never mind -_-